# Relative information gain for continuous RV

Tags: entropy, mutual-information

I am looking for a well-defined measure of the information gained about a vector $X$ from observing another vector $Y$. Both $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random vectors. For example, suppose that $Y=AX$, $A$ is a known constant matrix (not necessarily square) and $X$ is multivariate Normal. In the typical case $Var(X|Y)< Var(X)$. It is also possible that (a) $Var(X|Y)=0$, and (b) $Var(X|Y) = Var(X)$. Is there an entropy-based measure of (relative) information gain which in (a) is equal to 1 and in (b) is equal to 0?

Comment: I thought by definition $I(X;Y)=H(X)−H(X|Y)$, where I is the average mutual information. I'm finding your question confusing because isnt the information gain already an entropy based measure? If you use the equation $H(X|Y=y)=−\sum_x p_{X|Y}(x|y)lnp_{X|Y}(x|y)$ you can easily see the result for linearity and independence as mentioned above.

Comment: @mandata I thought so too, but the only definition of entropy I know implies that $H(X|Y)=-\infty$ in case (a), and then $I(X;Y)=\infty$. In other words the information gain, which I would define as $I(X;Y)/H(X)$, is not in general bounded between 0 and 1. Perhaps you are thinking about entropy for discrete variables.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already pointed out, the quantity you are interested in is the [conditional entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy).

In general, the [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) (i.e. entropy of 'continuous' functions, rather than of discrete functions) has some different properties, like $-\infty$ for absolute certainty.

However, bear in mind that when you compare variance to the (differential) entropy, you need to take log of the former, i.e. there is an inequality:

$$\tfrac{1}{2} \ln \left[ 2 \pi e\text{Var}(X) \right] \geq H(X)$$.

So, if you want to have to have your results in the range $[0,1]$ consider taking exp of entropy, i.e.

$$1-\frac{\exp[H(X|Y)]}{\exp[H(X)]}=1-\exp[-I(X;Y)],$$

where $I(X;Y)$ is the [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information).